# Image spin when hover over text

Tags: javascript, onhover

Right, I have a div with text in it, When I hover over the text it fades to red and has a margin left of 4px, It also has a image of a star next to it, what I want to achieve is to make the star spin when the text is hovered over but still have it turn red and have a margin left of 4px, any ideas?

Comment: Hard, without existing code... :)

Comment: Is the `<img>` a child or a sibling? If yes, should be easy once you post your code.

Comment: Okay, give me a second

Comment: <li class="margin"><span class="red"><img src="images/star.png" width="10" height="10" alt="star" class="star" />Strength and conditioning training</span></li>

Comment: Can you include your CSS?

Comment: span.red:hover {
 color:#C42626;   
   -webkit-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;  
   -moz-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;  
   -o-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;  
   transition:color 0.5s ease-in;}
span.red {
 color:#CCC;   
   -webkit-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;  
   -moz-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;  
   -o-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;  
   transition:color 0.5s ease-in;}

Comment: .star {
 
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
     
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;}
.star:hover {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}

Comment: @Ed, please post that code in your question instead of a comment. Please also consider creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can experiment with that code and get a better idea of the effect you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm new, When I posted it, it got rid of all the tags and only left the text

Comment: Then I should direct you to our [markdown editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thank you, It's all sorted now, thanks to Mooseman :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vPAcF/

CSS:

```
span.red:hover {
    color:#C42626;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
    transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
}
span.red:hover .star {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -0-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.star {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}
.star:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
span.red {
    color:#CCC;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
    transition:color 0.5s ease-in;
}
```